# My app is now in the Apple App Store but crashes during the splash screen

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store

My application is in the Apple App Store but when downloaded it crashes after the splash screen.

I thought the week long approval process was to ensure the quality of the app.

Version 1.0 of my app does run but I hear there is no way to roll it back. For now I have changed the availability date to the future so that people do not download it. When will it be taken out of the search results?

Thanks.

Comment: So the *exact* binary that you submitted doesn't crash, but the one that can be downloaded from the store does? That's certainly something worth contacting Apple about. I'd guess that it will be taken out of search results by the end of the day.

Comment: Do you want help with the crash or the date when it will be removed from the search?

Comment: +1 to Rob. If you're saying your app works, but Apple published a version that doesn't, then you probably want to call them. Of course, you might want to simply reboot your phone first - maybe you're phone is just having a bad day.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. I have received reviews on my app that it does not work and have verified myself. Unfortunately I don't have access to the binary right now so I cannot find out if it is the culprit.  Would Apple of approved an app binary that crashes? Maybe I should contact them?

Comment: Snce it is version 1.0, I suggest you remove the app from App Store, and submit the fix as a new app

Comment: Have you updated your iOS version since the version you submitted to AppStore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was taken out of search results by the end of the day.

Answer (score 0):

The approval process is not for QA testing.  (Of course, they will reject an app if it crashes while testing they are other for things, such as violation of various SDK rules, HIG guidelines, etc.)  A developer has to test and QA your apps themselves on the OS versions and the iOS device types for which they submit the app as appropriate for, and under stress conditions as well.  A developer also needs to make very certain that the build they submit is identical (except for certificate signing) to the builds they have tested.  (It is a common mistake to have different Build Settings or source files selected between the Release and Distribution builds.)

Comment: How could something that does not run possibly pass HIG guidelines?

Comment: @joe - Easy... apps which crash on devices or under OS versions other than the ones on which the HIG testing is being done, or which crash the 2nd (or Nth) time they are run.  Not that uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if a bad preference setting is the culprit.

Or if it worked only for you, then it may be the lack of a preference setting.  You may have created a good preference before the bug was introduced.